# Render form without value in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm building a form which have default value in some fields:

```
$builder->add('field', 'text', array('data' => 'Default value');
```

Then render this form field in Twig like:

```
{{ form_widget(form.field) }}
```

It's worked OK, but I don't want 'Default value' set in **input** tag rendered in HTML, because I only want this default value set internal that End-user doesn't aware about this value. Is there any built-in method in Symfony2 to handle it or I have to make some custom code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could modify your entity in order to do this:

```
class MyEntity{

    const DEFAULT_FOO = "Default value";
    // ...

    private $foo;

    // ...

    public function setFoo($foo){
        if ( $foo === null ){
            $foo = self::DEFAULT_FOO;
        }

        $this->foo = $foo;
    }

    // ...
}
```

And then make sure that you set `by_reference` in order to ensure setter is being invoked each time:

```
$builder->add('field', 'text', array(
    'by_reference' => true
));
```

Comment: Your solution is great Jovan, but my app doesn't have Entity, whenever user submit this form I pass this array result to an external API.

Comment: It look like that handling value manually is the only way in my case. But I'll select this as answer because it could help others.

Comment: Thanks :) Hope that someone will find it useful :)

Comment: Why do you introduce a new constant? Could you simply write the code as `private $foo = "Default value";` and a simple setter?

Comment: Most definitely. But, I like to avoid magic numbers/values in order to improve readability. ;) On the other hand, `private $foo = "Default value"` would not work as the `null` value would write over the `Default values` as soon as the setter gets invoked.

Answer (score 0):

As far i understand

try to add required false and handle it in your controller action.

```
$builder->add('field', 'text', array('required' => false));
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I'm just trying to find out any solution to handle this case without handle manually.